# How to produce error for item not being in array list

Tags: java

I'm trying to select an item from an array list by calling its ID number and I need a Dialog error to show up if the ID number is not associated with any item in the array list.

I know how to code a dialog box but I don't know how to make it pop out when the ID number I type in doesn't match anything in the array list.

Comment: What is the object of your arraylist?

Comment: Can you add some code that you already have?

Comment: Are you looking for `ArrayList#contains(Object o)` method?

Comment: Check if your ArrayList contains the id, if not throw an exception with meaningful message and at later point you can show on the Dialog box.

Comment: I already have IDs on the array items but I just need to somehow write a code to show an error if a user has not entered an ID that exists in the array when picking an item from the list to make it do something.
In my case I have two different arrays,one that stores Mobiles and another one that stores MP3s and the user has to select either one of them by entering their ID to make a call\download music.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Object myElement : myList) {
    if (myElement.getId() == id) {
        // handle gracefully
        break;
    }
}

// Make dialog box appear
```

As has been suggested, you probably want to use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for performance

Comment: Nothing wrong with you code. But, it's not a good practice to catch RuntimeExceptions especially when you know your code raises it.

Comment: Actually it was wrong anyway, because he wanted to use an element's ID, not the index in the `ArrayList`. I totally changed it

Comment: I already have IDs on the array items but I just need to somehow write a code to show an error if a user has not entered an ID that exists in the array when picking an item from the list to make it do something. In my case I have two different arrays,one that stores Mobiles and another one that stores MP3s and the user has to select either one of them by entering their ID to make a call\download music.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question, I think you are looking for something like

```
int id = getMahId();
ArrayList<?> mahList = getMahList();
if (!mahList.contains(getMahId())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does not contain id");
```

However, I think you are looking for a map, possibly a [HashMap.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) This more easily allows you to map an id to an item.

Comment: I already have IDs on the array items but I just need to somehow write a code to show an error if a user has not entered an ID that exists in the array when picking an item from the list to make it do something. In my case I have two different arrays,one that stores Mobiles and another one that stores MP3s and the user has to select either one of them by entering their ID to make a call\download music.

Comment: @user2258223 Ok, then what is your problem? You know how to create a dialog. You already have the ids. Throwing an error is easy enough. What specifically do you need assistance with?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
// add objects to list

String id; // get this from wherever
boolean found = false;
for (MyClass o : list) {
    found |= o.getId().equals(id);
}
```

Better way is to override the equals() method to compare ids.

```
public class MyClass {
    String id;
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof MyClass &&
            ((MyClass)o).getId().equals(id);
    }
    // hash code should agree with equals
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
    // rest of class omitted
}
```

Then to check, simply:

```
boolean found = list.contains(id);
```

Comment: I already have IDs on the array items but I just need to somehow write a code to show an error if a user has not entered an ID that exists in the array when picking an item from the list to make it do something. In my case I have two different arrays,one that stores Mobiles and another one that stores MP3s and the user has to select either one of them by entering their ID to make a call\download music.

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean foundObject = false;

for (MyObject myObject : myList) {
    if (id.equals(myObject.getId()) {
        foundObject = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!foundObject) {
    //Show dialog here
}
```

Comment: I already have IDs on the array items but I just need to somehow write a code to show an error if a user has not entered an ID that exists in the array when picking an item from the list to make it do something. In my case I have two different arrays,one that stores Mobiles and another one that stores MP3s and the user has to select either one of them by entering their ID to make a call\download music.